Is a function pointer variable always defined/legal for multithreading (thread-safe)(atomic) in C?
Edit: The Question was meant as "is a function pointer atomic in the C standard".
Is a variable, which is a pointer to a function itself, thread-safe?
With thread-safe, I mean, is the value always defined?
Like, is it always a legal value, the address of an existing function? (Some function I assigned at some point to this value.)
I think storing the value in the variable should always be a single assembler instruction (similar to "reading"). Considering that, it should be fine, shouldn't it?
NOTE: I mean on a single core CPU. (I'm not sure if this makes a difference.)
Example, for code, set_a() and do_something() in the code below could be called from any thread at any time.
Test.h
typedef int fn_t (int a);

void set_a(fn_t * fn);

void do_something(void);


Test.c
static fn_t * a;

void set_a(fn_t * fn){
    a = fn;
}

void do_something(void){

    if (a != NULL && a(1) == 0){
        printf(" Happend \n");
    }

    printf("Doing something else \n");
}


It is a data race, therefore undefined behavior. If the pointed-to function was jitted or came from a dll then you have no guarantee that the data the function points to is correct. This is very unlikely in practice, and will just work on most platforms

If there is any possibility that more than one thread can set the variable then you should protect it with a lock or semaphore.

@AhmedAEK If set_a() hasn't yet been called it will have its initial value of NULL, and the a != NULL check should catch that.

The issue of JIT applies to the function that calls set_a(), and is agnostic of whether threads are in use. I'm not sure the C spec allows for a function with a definition not to be defined when you reference it, so JIT should be transparent.

@AhmedAEK thank you, does it change something if i dont use JIT or DLL? (All my function addresses are known at compile time, its for an embedded system) *load time

I don't think it will cause bugs, but you could instead copy the pointer to the stack then do both oprations on it. in your code you have a time-of-check time-of-use bug. (Setting it back to null for example would invoke undefined behavior), again since it is not atomic the compiler is free to omit the copy to the stack and produce undefined behavior. As i said this is a data race and therefore UB.


Is a variable, which is a pointer to a function itself, thread-safe? With thread-safe, i mean is the value always defined? Like is it always a legal value, a adr of a existing function.

No, regardless of threading.  Neither object pointers nor function pointers  are automatically guaranteed to contain addresses of valid targets.  For example,
void (**p)(void) = malloc(sizeof(*p));

void (*fp1)(void) = (void (*)(void)) 0;
void (*fp2)(void) = (void (*)(void)) *p;

However, it is true that all functions live and keep the same address for the the entire run of the program, so once you take the address of an existing function, the result never becomes a dangling pointer.
It is also true that functions and their addresses are not thread-specific.  A function pointer valid in one thread is also valid and points to the same function in any other thread in the same run of the program.

I think storing the value in the variable should always be a single assembler instruction (similar to "reading"). Considering that it sould be fine, shouldnt it?

That has little to do with thread safety, and it is not a special characteristic of function pointers.  What you're asking seems more like whether accesses to objects of function pointer type are atomic.  But at the level of the C language, that is not much related to how any given CPU implements reads and writes of values of that type.  C has explicitly atomic types, but it does not recognize any accidentally atomic ones.

Example for code, set_a() and do_something() could be called from any thread at any time.

If one thread calls your set_a() and a different one calls your do_something(), without any synchronization between those calls, then the program contains a data race, and its behavior is undefined.  This is true as long as the type of a is not atomic, regardless of what its specific type is.

Actually, I can think of a case where your "functions always keep the same address (in a given program run)" statement is almost false, or at least somewhat misleading. Dynamically generated code. Foreign function interfacing for example, it is possible to create many native wrappers to the same foreign target.

@SoronelHaetir, this answer is directed at standard C, and dynamic function generation is not a feature of any version of the standard C language.  This is the appropriate context for a question with the tags and content that this one has.

"What you're asking seems more like whether accesses to objects of function pointer type are atomic. But at the level of the C language (...)"  yes this is what i ment thank you very much


Is a variable, which is a pointer to a function itself, thread-safe?

You are asking the wrong question. It doesn't matter whether the variable is "thread-safe" (whatever that means*) or not. Your code uses the variable in a way that is not thread-safe.
This expression, a != NULL && a(1) == 0 first tests the value, and then uses the pointer. Nothing prevents some other thread from changing the value between the test and the use.
Thread-safe variables and objects do not magically confer thread-safety upon the code that uses them. A program as a whole is not "thread-safe" unless it is thread-safe at every level.

* If someone says that a variable is "thread-safe," they usually mean that no thread will ever see the variable contain any value other than its initial value or a value that the program stored in it. I don't know whether C pointer variables always have that property or not.

C pointer variables are not implicitly _Atomic (relaxed ordering or otherwise).  On real implementations that aren't Deathstation 9000 intentionally hostile, it's unlikely a compiler would make asm that loads or stores in multiple parts, and asm for real-world CPUs normally guarantee atomicity for aligned loads / stores at least up to pointer width.  But it's easy to imagine e.g. a segmented memory model implementation for i386 where function pointers are 48-bit far pointers so aren't naturally atomic, or one with _Alignof(T*) == 1 so pointers can split across cache lines.

The other part of "thread safe" that people usually expect is guaranteed visibility, so e.g. do { tmp = shared_var; } while(tmp == NULL); won't hoist the load and be an infinite loop if it's initially NULL.  This is another part of what _Atomic gives you.  (Which you can also get from volatile on real CPUs because they have coherent cache across cores that run threads of the same program, but just use _Atomic with relaxed loads and stores if that's what you want.)

But yes, good point that the OP's code has a TOCTOU race if other threads can change a back to NULL.

The de facto definition of the term "thread safe" is if a function utilizes some special means to ensure there are no race conditions bugs: mutex, semaphore, critical section etc. There is also the term "re-entrant" usually meaning that the function is intrinsically safe without such means, for example if it modifies no shared resources to begin with.

@PeterCordes, I think you're telling me that accessing a naked variable from more than one thread without any synchronization is "UB." I'm embarassed not to have thought of that myself. In my defense, let me say that during the final five or so years of my career (I'm retired now) all of the C and C++ code that I wrote was for tiny, embedded, single-board computers. We exclusively used the manufacturer's proprietary development tools, and if we had any question about what was "safe" or not, we looked it up in the manufacturer's documentation, not in the language standard.

@Lundin, IMO that's a hollow definition. How do you explain it to a newbie who doesn't know what "race condition bugs" means? Also, it's a very low-level explanation. If I'm going to use somebody else's software component in my project, I want to know what promises it keeps, and I want to know whether or not it will keep them if its methods are concurrently called by two or more threads. That's the definition of "thread safety" that I was taught, but like I said to Peter (above), I'm not really in the loop anymore. Maybe the consensus has changed.

Yes, two or more unsynchronized accesses to a non-_Atomic variable is data-race UB unless they're all reads.  (And in practice it's safe for volatile variables, especially with compilers like GCC and Clang which try to support volatile as having relaxed-atomic load/store for narrow-enough types.)  https://lwn.net/Articles/793253/ (Who's afraid of a big bad optimizing compiler?) is a good article about all the obvious and subtle ways compilers can break code that shares plain variables even when you use memory barriers to make sure loads/stores aren't just optimized away.

@SolomonSlow Newbies aren't supposed to work with multi-threading in the first place. It is a more advanced topic.

thank you, im just concerned about the tearing of the pointer value (which isnt garanteed by the C standard apperantly). (as long as a existing function is called, its all fine in my usecase (and the value is not allowed to be set to NULL again if changed)).
Because i think a call instruction should be a singular instruction, so if the ptr value exists, it should always jmp to a existing function?

I mean does anyone know if anything can happen, if you change a function ptr (in one thread), while another thread is in the function call of the function the ptr pointer to before ? I believe there are not?

@z4x, even if a() is "a singular instruction," How would that have any bearing on whether or not the thread sees a torn value of a? If you wrote b=a, might that not also be a single instruction? And, could it not potentially assign a torn value to b?

@SolomonSlow sry i ment: b=a can tear, because if its for example 64bit values and my asm is for 32bit, i need atleast 2 instructions to change b to a. So if after the first asm instruction the first 32bit are set, and then an interrupt happnes and the thread is changed, another thread could see the teared value. And for a function call, the asm "call" itself is just one instruction, And i just ment if the value asm "call" used is not teared, there should not be a problem? or is there? (im just curiouse, in my program i will not allow changing the function ptr at runtime like this anymore)

or atleast i couldnt find a 2 asm instruction function call, but maybe they exist?

@z4x, OK, So, I could have said that better. For one thing, when I said, b=a, I could have said that I'm still talking about the same a. That is to say, a pointer variable. But the real issue is, that on some architectures, as Peter Cortes pointed out, a single pointer variable can be split across cache lines. When that's allowed, and when it happens, then a single instruction that refers to the variable can cause more than one fetch operation to get the bits from memory. It doesn't matter what the instruction is going to do with those bits once it gets them.
